# Movie Night - February 2020

Tags: discussion, community-event, movie-night

Wow, it's been two years already? I've been thinking about starting up Movie Nights again and here we are. Unlike our previous Movie Nights, I've pre-selected the movie we're going to be watching:

## Saban's Power Rangers

[image]

The reason for this is that I'd like put out some feelers to see who's interested in Movie Nights again. As for time and date, I'm thinking about this weekend, Saturday at 11:00 PM UTC-0.

In summary,

- Movie: Power Rangers
- Date: 2020/02/15
- Time: 11:00 PM UTC-0

Let me know in [The Bridge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) if you have any questions.

Comment: I would, but I have meatspace plans for the night.